# How can I do a search and replace in a PHP string based on values in a JSON string?

Tags: php

In PHP I have this json string with search and replace words

```
$json = '[{"Original":"test1","Replacement":"test1a"},{"Original":"test2","Replacement":"test2a"}]';
```

Now I want to do a search and replace in a text string for all items in this json file.

```
$searchReplaceArray = '[{"Original":"test1","Replacement":"test1a"},{"Original":"test2","Replacement":"test2a"}]';

$text1 = 'Hello test1, let me see if test2 is also replaced...';
$text2 = str_ireplace(array_keys($searchReplaceArray), array_values($searchReplaceArray),$text1);

echo 'Original: ' . $text1 . '<br>';
echo 'Replace: '  . $text2;
```

I expect $text2 to be: "Hello test1a, let me see if test2a is also replaced..."

However, it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would have converted the JSON using `json_decode()` and gone from there, but its not valid JSON

Comment: Okay, so I changed the json string into [{"Original":"test1","Replacement":"test1a"},{"Original":"test2","Replacement":"test2a"}]. And then I used json_decode to get a PHP array.

When dumping , I get this:

array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Original"]=> string(5) "test1" ["Replacement"]=> string(6) "test1a" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Original"]=> string(5) "test2" ["Replacement"]=> string(6) "test2a" } }

Comment: json_decode($json, true) to get pho array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// It's not a valid Json,  so you need add square brackets around it
$searchReplaceArray = '['. $json .']';

$searchReplaceArray = json_decode($searchReplaceArray, true);
// get search array
$Original = array_column($searchReplaceArray , 'Original');
// get replacement array
$Replacement = array_column($searchReplaceArray , 'Replacement');

$text1 = 'Hello test1, let me see if test2 is also replaced...';
$text2 = str_ireplace($Original, $Replacement,$text1);

echo 'Original: ' . $text1 . '<br>';
echo 'Replace: '  . $text2;

// Replace: Hello test1a, let me see if test2a is also replaced...
```